# Won't boot because of rc.local start up script

Tags: linux, svn, virtual-machine, startupscript

Environment :

Virtualization software : VMware Workstation 12 Player

Guest Machine : Red Hat 6.4

Host Machine : Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Question :

I'm trying to execute automatically a svn update at the boot of my virtual machine. I edited the rc.local file like this :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't 
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

sleep 10

svn update path/to/repository

exit 0
```

But with this the virtual machine won't boot, it keeps loading (If I remove the svn command line, there is no problem). And if I try to shutdown or restart the guest, we can see this :

[image: Guest machine window]

So it means that svn command was executed but it didn't work. I already tried writing "svn update --username user --password xxx" but same result. How do I get the svn command to run?

Answer (score 0):

What if you create the file in **/etc/init.d/svnserve**

```
#!/bin/bash 
### BEGIN INIT INFO 
# Provides:          svnserve 
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog 
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# X-Interactive:     true 
# Short-Description: Start/stop svnserve 
### END INIT INFO 

svnserve -d -r /PATH/TO/YOUR/REPOSITORY
```

**Make it Executable:**

```
chmod u+x /etc/init.d/svnserve
```

**Create links from runlevels to the script:**

```
 update-rc.d svnserve
```

**Then check if the links were created correctly**

```
find /etc/ -name '*svnserve*'
```

Best regards

Xsi

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! There is already a svnserve file : http://pasted.co/4000d4db . I modified it to make it look like yours, I used chkconfig but still it doesn't do anything at boot.